# Currency input masking in jasny bootstrap?

Tags: jquery, jasny-bootstrap

Can any body help me with currency masking in input field ? I am using jasny bootstrap but not able to make currency combination or float values.

I want to put `.` anywhere in the field once with the numbers and jasny allows me to use `?` for any character. I tried below combinations.

```
9?.9999
?.99999
```

but none of them full fill my requirement.

Comment: Please show us what you tried and how it is failing...

Comment: I have this problem some days ago and changed to http://plentz.github.io/jquery-maskmoney/

Answer (score 0):

It's not supported. Use an alternative plugin like [jquery.inputmask](http://robinherbots.github.io/jquery.inputmask/) instead.